# How to upgrade my computer's RAM?

Tags: windows-7

My computer does not supports proper gaming in 2GB RAM   in Windows 8, 8.1 and 10 both in x86 bit as well as x64 bit architecture. Games only run properly in Windows 7 and XP of x86 bit as well as x64 bit. How to resolve this problem? 
   My processor is" Intel Core 2 Duo". Speed :- 2.43 Ghz.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. Are you saying your Windows machine only has 2 GB of RAM? To better help us, ignore the gaming problems for now, is your goal to upgrade to more RAM? The names of the games may be helpful, because it could be a CPU problem.

Comment: @DrZoo I won't even bother to ask what he has exactly. It just isn't worth it, to invest money in. (See my answer below.)

Comment: As the display driver model changed quite significantly between Windows 7 and Windows 8 it might well be that your graphics card is now completely unsupported in 8 and above. Quite a lot has been made obsolete in the last 10 years

Comment: You need to post the exact model and make of your PC for more help.

Answer (score 2):

A Core2Duo CPU is 8 or more years old.
No modern game will work well on it, no matter how much RAM you'll throw at it.
It will also won't play nicely with any modern video-card, which is also a requirement for a decent gaming experience.

A Core2Duo means a very old system. Don't bother upgrading.
It is a total waste of money. But a new system. Even the cheapest Core-i3 or Ryzen-3 new system you can find will be MUCH faster than what you have now.